# Is there a difference between: "The coming year" and "next year"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, differences, word-usage

If it were now January, would "the coming year" be taken to mean this year?
If it were November would "the coming year" refer to the next calendar year or a period running from November to November?

Comment: If it's the beginning of the year, it's the current year. If it's near the end, it's the next year. In the middle, I think it means the next 12 months. There's no fixed dividing point, so don't use the phrase when it's likely to be confusing.

Comment: Also be aware that the interpretation of "next" can vary between cultures.

Answer (score 1):

> If it's the beginning of the year, it's the current year. If it's near the end, it's the next year. In the middle, I think it means the next 12 months. There's no fixed dividing point, so don't use the phrase when it's likely to be confusing.

Taken from the comments as the OP acknowledged it as being a helpful answer.

Comment: Yet it doesn't even answer the question if it doesn't explain what "the coming year" means.

Comment: @thorr18 This answer does indeed answer the question, insofar as Livrecache thinks it can be answered. The word "it's" refers to what the phrase "the coming year" means. I agree that there an inherent ambiguity as to whether "year" means any period lasting a year, or specifically a calendar year. In any case the context might help.